# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in a pie chart

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, pie-chart

I am new to d3.js, and while making a pie chart, I am getting the following error:

```
'd3.v4.js:13909 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of 
undefined'
```

My data is of the following format:

```
  var company = [

 {  
    "company_code": 1,  
    "company_name": "Walmart",
    "health_safety": 3.6,
    "wages": 5,
    "recommended": 4  
  },
  { 
    "company_code": 2,
    "company_name": "HEB",
    "health_safety": 3,
    "wages": 2,
    "recommended": 1
  },
  ]
```

The code of the following is as follows:

```
var width = 400;
var height = 400;


//sampling out the data which doesn't have the min_company_code -- for now -- for initial screen



var path = d3.arc()
             .outerRadius(width / 2 - 10)
             .innerRadius(width / 4); 


d3.select('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
  .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ', ' + height / 2 + ')')
    .classed('chart', true);

var company_codeData = company.filter(d => d.company_code === 1);
var health = company_codeData[0]['health_safety'];
var parameters = [health, 5 - health];


var arcs = d3.pie()
            .value(parameters);

var path = d3.arc()
             .outerRadius(width / 2 - 10)
             .innerRadius(width / 4);

d3.select('.chart')
      .selectAll('.arc')
      .data(arcs)  // This is the line that gives me the error!!
      .enter()
      .append('path')
        .classed('arc', true)
        .attr('fill', function(d, i){
          return data[i].color;
        })
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .attr('d', path);
```

Is the function being called before the data is loaded? If yes, how do I fix the error? I read that I need to load the data in a callback, but I can't figure out how
How do I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you're trying to do (which I have no idea, since you have a data array with several objects that you're filtering, extracting **one** value and using it to create a 2-element array), this is incorrect:

```
var arcs = d3.pie()
    .value(parameters);
```

You shoudn't pass the actual data to the `value` method of the pie generator. You must pass the data to the pie generator itself. In your case:

```
var arcs = d3.pie()(parameters);
```

Also, there is no `data` or `color` in your snippet, I changed it to:

```
.attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return i ? "blue" : "green";
})
```

Which returns `blue` or `green` instead.

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
var company = [{
  "company_code": 1,
  "company_name": "Walmart",
  "health_safety": 3.6,
  "wages": 5,
  "recommended": 4
}, {
  "company_code": 2,
  "company_name": "HEB",
  "health_safety": 3,
  "wages": 2,
  "recommended": 1
}];

var width = 400;
var height = 400;

var path = d3.arc()
  .outerRadius(width / 2 - 10)
  .innerRadius(width / 4);


d3.select('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ', ' + height / 2 + ')')
  .classed('chart', true);

var company_codeData = company.filter(d => d.company_code === 1);
var health = company_codeData[0]['health_safety'];
var parameters = [health, 5 - health];


var arcs = d3.pie()(parameters);

var path = d3.arc()
  .outerRadius(width / 2 - 10)
  .innerRadius(width / 4);

d3.select('.chart')
  .selectAll('.arc')
  .data(arcs) // This is the line that gives me the error!!
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .classed('arc', true)
  .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return i ? "blue" : "green";
  })
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('d', path);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in this snippet.

var company_codeData = company.filter(d => d.company_code === 1);
var health = company_codeData[0]['health_safety'];
var parameters = [health, 5 - health];

for `company`, which is an array of objects, how do you know that property exists?  additionally did you console.log the 3 variables to make sure they are defined?

Comment: The problem is the pie generator, not that snippet.